# Incorrect parameter type for operator '>='

Tags: formula, formula-field

My start/end date was `Date` and I have changed it `Date/Time` datatype after doing that my formula is broken:

```
IF(ISPICKVAL(Employee_Status__c, "ACTIVE") , 
       TODAY() >= Emp_Start_Date__c && TODAY() <= Emp_End_Date__c , FALSE)
```

> Incorrect parameter type for operator '>='. Expected Date, received
>   DateTime (Related field: Formula)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast the DateTime value into a Date for use with other Date values. Wrap your `Emp_Start_Date__c` field in a `DATEVALUE` function to cast it, or use `NOW()` as a comparison operator, as it returns a DateTime, which you can use without casts.

From the [Working with Date and Date/Time documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=formula_using_date_datetime.htm):

> Date and Date/Time aren’t interchangeable data types, so when you want to perform operations between Date and Date/Time values, you need to convert the values so they are both the same type. Some functions (such as `YEAR()`, `MONTH()`, and `DAY()`) also only work on Date values, so Date/Time values must be converted first.
>
> Use the `DATEVALUE( date/time )` function to return the Date value of a Date/Time. For example, to get the year from a Date/Time, use `YEAR( DATEVALUE( date/time ) ) )`.